# how to check collision with a disabled collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in a project that have 2 dimensions, a red one, and a blue one.

every time the player press 'F' the dimension changes, and then all the objects from the actual dimensions are disabled while the other are enabled.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)) {
            if (seeingRed == false) {
                seeingRed = true;
                setRed();               
            } else {
                seeingRed = false;
                setBlue();             
            }
}

public void setRed() {
        redObjects.SetActive(true);
        blueObjects.SetActive(false);    
}

public void setBlue () {
        redObjects.SetActive(false);
        blueObjects.SetActive(true);       
}
```

I want to check if the actual position of the player has a disabled object, and if so, don't change the dimensions, I tried use Raycast but it doesn't work since a disabled object has no physics.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a public boolean variable that stores the current dimension, then you can reference that variable whenever you want to know the current dimension.

```
public bool currentDimension = false //false means red dimension, true means blue
```

`Edit:` thanks for clarifying.

This might help you:https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Instead of disabling the entire object, you can disable only the sprite renderer of the different dimensions. You can then set the player to only collide with its own layer, and change the layer of the dimensions. Then send a raycast from the player and check for collisions from the opposite layer.

Comment: is for that reason tha i have the 'seeingRed' bool, but the problem is that i can't know if i am inside a blue structure before press 'F', and if i am, when i press 'F' i will change dimension and appear clipping inside the wall

Comment: Ok I edited my answer to hopefully solve you problem.

Comment: It seems like this is the only way to do it. If you are in a red dimension, disable all of blue object's mesh renderers and set all colliders to trigger. Then reverse